# Output results from cat into different files with names specified into an array

Tags: arrays, bash, cat

I would like to do cat on several files, which names are stored in an array:

```
cat $input | grep -v "#" | cut -f 1,2,3
```

Here the content of the array:

```
echo $input
1.blastp 2.blastp 3.blastp 4.blastp 5.blastp 6.blastp 7.blastp 8.blastp 9.blastp 10.blastp 11.blastp 12.blastp 13.blastp 14.blastp 15.blastp 16.blastp 17.blastp 18.blastp 19.blastp 20.blastp
```

This will work just nicely. Now, I am struggling in storing the results into proper output files. So I want to also store the output into files which names are stored into another array:

```
echo $out_in
1_pairs.tab 2_pairs.tab 3_pairs.tab 4_pairs.tab 5_pairs.tab 6_pairs.tab 7_pairs.tab 8_pairs.tab 9_pairs.tab 10_pairs.tab 11_pairs.tab 12_pairs.tab 13_pairs.tab 14_pairs.tab 15_pairs.tab 16_pairs.tab 17_pairs.tab 18_pairs.tab 19_pairs.tab 20_pairs.tab

cat $input | grep -v "#" | cut -f 1,2,3 > "$out_in"
```

My problem is: 
When I don't use the "" I will get 'ambiguous redirect' error.

When I use them, a single file will be created that comes by the name:

```
1_pairs.tab?2_pairs.tab?3_pairs.tab?4_pairs.tab?5_pairs.tab?6_pairs.tab?7_pairs.tab?8_pairs.tab?9_pairs.tab?10_pairs.tab?11_pairs.tab?12_pairs.tab?13_pairs.tab?14_pairs.tab?15_pairs.tab?16_pairs.tab?17_pairs.tab?18_pairs.tab?19_pairs.tab?20_pairs.tab
```

I don't get why the input array is read with no problem but that's not the case for the output array...

any ideas?

Thanks a lot!
D.

Comment: Is $input an array or a string? It looks like a string

Comment: $input was created as follows: `split=$(cat /work_beegfs/sunam133/Pantoea_ProtFamBlast/splits.txt | sed -n ${SLUU
RM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}p)
input=$(for i in $split; do echo ${i:15:-6}.blastp; done)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot redirect output that way, the output is a stream of characters and the redirection can not know when to switch to the next file. You need a loop over input files.
Assuming that the file names do not contain spaces:

```
for fn in $input; do
    grep -v "$fn" | cut -f 1,2,3 >"${fn%%.*}_pairs.tab"
done
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Running in a loop is not exactly what I wanted to do because I wanted to run the processes in parallel, but I can now properly redirect the output.